# Php syntax, database request with user input component

Tags: php

I need some help with the php syntax for when user input is a variable in the request to the database.

The below manually enters values:

```
"UPDATE customer SET first_name= 'Me2' WHERE id = ' 13 ' ";
```

However i want the user to be able to enter values such as this:

```
"UPDATE customer SET first_name=".$edit_first_name.", WHERE id=".$edit_id."\"";
```

When i run the above it doesn't work as the first example script does.
An i'm assuming it's a syntax problem, an there is no display on the page to indicate the issue location. Please help

Comment: What is the datatype if field `id` ??

Comment: It is a primary key in the database, and is a int

Comment: Why you compare with space before and after in `id` ??

Comment: `"UPDATE customer SET first_name='".$edit_first_name."' WHERE id=$edit_id";`

Comment: It works! thank you so much saty <3

Comment: you'r welcome @Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. Don't insert `,` before `WHERE` & put single quotes around string value.

```
"UPDATE customer SET first_name='".$edit_first_name."' WHERE id=".$edit_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss simple quotes `''` around your `$edit_first_name` as it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final **query:**

```
$update="UPDATE customer SET first_name=".$edit_first_name." WHERE id=".$edit_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this statement, maybe it could solve your problem:

```
"UPDATE customer SET first_name ='$edit_first_name' WHERE id='$edit_id'";
```